# cached NSData object can't be used after retrieval

Tags: ios, caching, uiimage, nsdata

I am caching an `NSData` object containing image data retrieved from the web. The image displays correctly before caching. When I retrieve the data object from the cache, the data can no longer be used to create a UIImage, even though the data objects are identical.

Please see the relevant snippets of my code below

```
NSData *webData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webPath]; //retrieve from web
UIImage *webImage = [UIImage imageWithData:webData]; //works fine

[webData writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES]; //cache
NSData *cacheData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath]; //get from cache
if ([cacheData isEqualToData:webData]) NSLog(@"Equal"); //Data objects are equal

UIImage *cacheImage = [UIImage imageWithData:cacheData]; //cacheImage is nil
```

I can fix the problem by changing the way I store my data to the cache

```
NSData *temp = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(webImage, 1.0):
[temp writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Now the `webData` and `cacheData` are no longer equal, but `cacheImage` is not nil and displays properly.

EDIT - After a bit more testing, I realized I get the same problem using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` as well.

Anyone know why this would be?
Thanks.

Comment: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(webImage, 1.0)` is not compressing your image Data.

Comment: Can you log the results of the writeToURL?  Also log cacheData?  My guess is that the write/read is failing.  The cacheData comes out nil so then it's not equal to the webData

Comment: I have logged the results and the caching is working fine. The webData and the cacheData are equal and not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the problem was that I was trying to do all this before my view controller was fully loaded.